# Encoding issue mysql

Tags: mysql, functions, encryption

I'm using the MD5 hash function of MySQL to hash some data I import into the database from a CSV file.
The issue is that some lines have an incorrect hash (but not all of them).
When I use a query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET email_md5 = (SELECT MD5(email))
```

MySQL inserts some wrong hashes in the table but when I check with using

```
SELECT MD5('email@email.com')
```

I find the correct answer.

Any idea how to check the encoding of the data I import in the database?

**UPDATE #1**
For this email *onachba@i-pcom.com* (not existing anymore)
Mysql insert this hash when I using MySQL query (the first in this post) with data in database from the CSV

> c62804a6d7122356cf5f261ebf860684

But when I insert the same email with my hands in database and replay the same query I find this hash (and is the correct hash)

> c31383bbaee83e9704fd7b0ad52581ca

**UPDATE #2**
We using mysql 8 and adminer
I feel it is a problem of encoding.
When I select the line for edit it from adminer and save it without any changes the browser recognize it like an email (she becomes clickable link with *mailto:*) + after this when I replay the query he add the good hash ! !
**The row don't recognize like an email** in adminer give me *wrong hash*
but
the lines from adminer **recognize like an email** have the *good hash*...
This is f*** creazy !

**UPDATE #3**
For datatype, it's ***varchar(200) NULL***
With another email where I find a MD5 issue
From MySQL with

```
SELECT MD5(email) FROM mytable WHERE id = 'theID';
```

> f6cd93fc748b7c856a74e6037f6e14f5

```
SELECT HEX(email) FROM mytable WHERE id = 'theID';
```

> 627269636540696775616E6573747564696F2E636F6D0D

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm having difficulty understanding your question. You say that `MySQL inserts some wrong hashes in the table` and then that if you `check with using SELECT MD5('email@email.com')` you get the `correct answer`. Can you show us a couple of examples where your system **is** working and where it **is not** working so that we can get a better idea of your problem?

Comment: Is asking the purpose of an md5 hash of email going to cause embarrassment?

Comment: @danblack - why is wanting to anonymise one's data a potential source of embarrassment? One might want to prove to a client that one has a certain number of emails but not want to reveal those ids before a contract is signed for example...

Comment: @Vérace It's exactly that. We have to find duplicate users from the client for split promotion between existing customers.

Comment: Fair enough - now we know **why** you want to do it. But now, I'd really like to know **what EXACTLY** it is you want to do? Some examples with data would be good - use a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6ddf243c83712778e575c4ce838efdb7) for example! Also, please specify your MySQL version - they've introduced lots of new features so it's (very) important!

Comment: You're doing somthing wrong - [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e864c89a62cf5b56f26b36c21089c11c) works perfectly using your original SQL - i.e. `UPDATE mytable SET email_md5 = (SELECT MD5(email));`. There's something you've missed! Version of MySQL? I find it difficult to imagine that a bug in the MD5 implementation wouldn't have been discovered yet! Works with the fiddle on 5.6, 5.7, 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2, 10.3 and 10.4.

Comment: @Vérace I don't think is an issue from MD5, I make new update. Thx for your help again.

Comment: What was the datatype of `email`?

Comment: Please provide `HEX(...)` of the email that gives the wrong MD5.

Comment: @RickJames Before all, really thx for your contribution on stackexchange. I find often your answers and again thx to look out my issue !  

I do **UPDATE #3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Carriage Return (hex 0D) at the end of

```
627269636540696775616E6573747564696F2E636F6D0D
                                            ^^
```

Recommend you trim emails of all "whitespace" before feeding them into your database in any way.

To confirm with your original email:

```
SELECT MD5('onachba@i-pcom.com');
+----------------------------------+
| MD5('onachba@i-pcom.com')        |
+----------------------------------+
| c31383bbaee83e9704fd7b0ad52581ca |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT MD5(CONCAT('onachba@i-pcom.com', UNHEX('0D')));
+------------------------------------------------+
| MD5(CONCAT('onachba@i-pcom.com', UNHEX('0D'))) |
+------------------------------------------------+
| c62804a6d7122356cf5f261ebf860684               |
+------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: OMG ! You got it !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
UPDATE mytable SET email_md5 = MD5(email) WHERE email_md5 != MD5(email)
```